# Handle directline Tokens and their "expires_in"

Tags: azure, botframework, postman

With [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) I send a `POST` to `https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate` with the Header `Authorization: Bearer MySecret`

The response is

```
{
  "conversationId": "MyConversationID",
  "token": "MyToken",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

Now I can go to this URL with the token

`https://directline.botframework.com/embed/MyName?t=MyToken`

and I have a chat opened. After (I assume) 3600 seconds I cannot reach the URL anymore as it is expired.

I can "refresh" my token by sending a POST via Postman to `https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/refresh` with this Header `Authorization: Bearer MyToken` and it gives me this response

```
{
  "conversationId": "MyConversationID",
  "token": "MySecondToken",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

I assume that `https://directline.botframework.com/embed/MyName?t=MyToken` will still run out after 3600 seconds but I can then continue the chat with `https://directline.botframework.com/embed/MyName?t=MySecondToken` as they have the same `conversationId`. Yet it also will expire after 3600 seconds.

Is it possible to set my own `expires_in` value?

Is it possible to remove `expires_in` so the token is permanent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change the `expires_in` value. It is also not possible to remove it, either. Doing so would defeat the purpose behind issuing and using tokens which is to provide a level of security and obfuscation. By using tokens coupled with the conversationId, you are making it harder for unsavory individuals to gain access to your application and data.

It is not absolutely necessary or required to use a token (it depends on your application needs). You can always use your secret, just do so carefully. You can read more about the use of tokens and secrets in the BotFramework docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#secrets-and-tokens).

If you plan on using tokens, then automate the call to refresh the token before it expires. Then swap the token out for the new.

Hope of help!